# RobotFramework: SikuliLibrary: Set Ocr Text Read, Get text keyword not working

Tags: windows, testing, ocr, robotframework

I am using Sikuli library with Robotframework(RF) for windows app testing. Followed this link for configuring SikuliLibrary with RF.

https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary

'Set Ocr Text Read' & 'Get Text' keywords are not working in RobotFramework.Error msg is gives as picture below. Similar error msg for 'Set Ocr Text Read'.

[Please click here to see error msg for 'Get Text' keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiBdM.png)

But in keyword documentation of Sikuli these 2 keywords are mentioned. Sikuli Library is imported properly. Others Sikuli keywords are working fine except these 2.

Need your kind help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do they throw an error? Are they returning the wrong text?

Comment: I have edited my question. Would you check pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had a look at [SikuliLibrary](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary)

In fact the Keyword "Get Text" was only added at September 12th this year.
Since the latest version 0.1.5 on pypi is from May 16th, "Get Text" is not included in the package you get with pip.

You have to follow the steps mentioned on GitHub under

**Build With Maven**

to get the latest version containing the changes made after May 16th.